# Mixed ordering by date and by type

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So let's say I have a database that looks like this

```
Posts
id | author_id | created_at
 1           1    1.day.ago
 2           1    2.day.ago
 3           2    3.day.ago
 4           1    4.day.ago

Authors
id | type
 1   Male
 2   Female
```

I want to do a query on these posts so that they return in desc order of created, but also going through all the types.

So if I just did:

```
Post.order('created_at desc')
```

I would get:

```
Posts
id | author_id | created_at
 1           1    1.day.ago
 2           1    2.day.ago
 3           2    3.day.ago
 4           1    4.day.ago
```

But let's say instead I want the results to be in this order:

```
Posts
id | author_id | created_at
 1           1    1.day.ago
 3           2    3.day.ago
 2           1    2.day.ago
 4           1    4.day.ago
```

So that I get first the most recent post from author 1, then the most recent post from author 2, even if it's older than the next post from author 1, then, since there are no more posts from author 2, it returns the rest in normal created_at order.

Let's assume there will never be more than 20 authors or so, but I always want to cycle through the most recent posts from each other, then the next most recent one from each, etc.

Is this possible to do in sql?

Comment: in sql it would be `order by id asc, created_at asc`, which leads to try - `Post.order('order by id asc, created_at asc')` ?..

Comment: @VaoTsun The id of the posts shouldn't be relevant to the ordering I've described here though. Just the created_at and the author_id are what I would want to be ordering by. Ordering by id might work for the example data I provided but not what I described below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand, one way is:

```
with Posts(id , author_id , created_at) as(
select 1       ,    1    ,'2017-09-17'::date union all
select 2       ,    1    ,'2017-09-16'::date union all
select 3       ,    2    ,'2017-09-15'::date union all
select 5       ,    2    ,'2017-09-10'::date union all
select 4       ,    1    ,'2017-09-14'::date  
)

select * from (
    select * ,row_number() over(partition by author_id order by created_at desc) as rn  
    from Posts
) t
order by rn, created_at desc
```

Comment: Why do you need the additional `order by created_at desc`? This is already incorporated in the `row_number`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger - When different users ranked as same number, then priority is to select most recent from they.

Comment: I don't think so, when different authors are ranked the same, the priority is author_id. The ranking already makes sure the most recent is at the top.

Comment: @HoneyBadger - The ranking makes sure that most recent for same author_id is at the top, not from different users when they have same rank. look at this: http://rextester.com/PCP1360 there is not guaranteed that most recent row will be at top

Comment: That's what I meant. OP's requirement: "... I get first the most recent post from author 1, then the most recent post from author 2". So not most recent post should be on top, but most recent post *of 1st author*.

Comment: @HoneyBadger - Well, if after ranking, ordering by `author_id` is more important than ordering by  `created_at`, then you are correct and `order by rn, author_id` needed instead of  `order by rn, created_at desc`

Answer (score 1):

You can order by a custom order using something like:

```
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY author_id ORDER BY created_at DESC)
,        author_id
```

If you add it to the select, you can see the result more easy, and apply tweaks where necessary.

At least, this is allowed in sql server, I assume likewise for postgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

We can assign a row number across a partition on authors, with the most recent posts being assigned the lowest row numbers.  Then order by this row number, followed by the author id to break the tie.

```
select
    t.id,
    t.author_id,
    t.created_at
from
(
    select id, author_id, created_at,
        row_number() over (partition by author_id order by created_at desc) rn
    from Posts
) t
order by
    t.rn,
    t.author_id
```